# Install ng-table with bower

Tags: angularjs, bower, ngtable, meanjs, bower-install

hi I have a problem installing ng-table with bower

```
bower install ng-table
"module.js:340"
    "throw err;"
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'insight' 
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) 
at Module.require (module.js:364:17) 
at require (module.js:380:17) 
at ensureInsight (C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\util\analytics.js:24:23) 
at Object.setup (C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\util\analytics.js:43:9) 
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower:72:11) 
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Comment: run `bower update` and then try with sudo

Comment: be aware that ng-table is no longer supported on bower: https://github.com/esvit/ng-table#installing

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried installing bower globally.
npm install -g bower and bower install worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
bower install ng-table-bundle --save
```

from: https://github.com/Greenek/bower-ng-table

Answer (score 1):

I tried `sudo npm install -g bower` first and then was able to use `bower install ng-table` after having this issue.